# Setting Timer in ngx_core_module

Tags: c, nginx

I want a particular function to be called every 15seconds (i.e I need to setup a timer) in a core nginx module that i have written.

Here is the [code](http://pastebin.com/GnqZZEaK) that I have written by referring some examples online. The `ngx_monitoring_init_process()` is the `'init process'` function in my `'ngx_monitoring_module'`

The module compiles OK, but the timer doesn't work, any idea why ?

Comment: What does the timer do when it doesn't work? Any error messages?

Comment: the `timer_callback()` is not invoked. But code in `ngx_monitoring_init_process` is executed. No error messages.